# Existe alguma forma de fixar o IP dos Notebooks do Google Colab?

Tags: python, mongodb, google, ip

Sou Analista de Dados de uma empresa, e minha principal ferramenta de trabalho hoje é o Python... Como a empresa ainda está em fase de crescimento eu realizava grande parte das análises localmente, porém com o tempo fui levando meus códigos para os Notebooks do Google Colab para que outros membros da equipe pudessem ter acesso.

Minha fonte de dados é um DataLake do Mongodb que eu acesso via Pymongo, para isso o meu IP foi adicionado na lista de permissões.. O problema é que ao rodar os meus códigos nos Notebooks da Google eu percebi que esse IP vai sendo alterado com o tempo, e toda a praticidade que me motivou a colocar meus códigos online foi perdida.

Sabem se existe alguma forma de contornar esse problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não. O google colabs é um serviço online e gratuito - e eles só podem oferecer isso justamente pela facilidade que é criar containers que se comportam como máquinas virtuais na nuvem.

O que voc^Çe pdoe fazer é contratar uma máquina na nuvem (pode ser no google, amazon, digital ocean, ou outro provedor de sua preferência), contratar o recurso de IP fixo (bem mais comum nesses casos, acho até que ainda é o padrão) e subir uma instância do Jupyter notebook -
A maior dificuldade aí é o contrário: impedir que qualquer um possa acessar o seu notebook - o que dá pra fazer com regras de firewall na máquina virtual (ruim, aí depende de você ter uma faixa de IPs fixos em casa), ou usar ssh + redirecionamento de portas para acessar o jupyter em sua instância privada (bom).

A grande vantagem dessa abordagem é poder passar código mais estruturado do seu notebook para arquivos Python puro, que aí podem ser colocados em controle de versão, podem ser testados com testes unitários, não precisam expor credênciais de conexão ao banco de dados externo aos usuários do notebook, e várias outras coisas.

Comment: Entendi amigo.

Muito obrigado!